# (Errno 13) Permission denied for pem file in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, paramiko

I have uploaded the `<>.pem` file inside the deployment package of AWS Lambda so that I can use it inside the lambda handler as:

```
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("<>.pem")
```

However, while running the code, Lambda gives this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<>.pem'
```

How do I work fix this permissions error?

Comment: What permissions does `<>.pem` file have?

Comment: I did `chmod 600` to it.  Do you think I need to change the permissions?

Comment: Well it is obviously a problem with file permissions. Who is the file owner? If it is root, using `chmod 600` on it it won't let you read it.